# Android programical set attribute for xml widgets

Tags: android

in application i can simply define `attr.xml` into `values` and use that into design layout. but i can not set this attributes programical into widgets, for example i have this attribute:

```
<declare-styleable name="ButtonTextStyle">
    <attr name="font_button">
        <enum name="consolas"      value="0" />
        <enum name="times"    value="1" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

and i can use this attribute into xml by:

```
<com.sample.app.Widgets.ButtonTextStyle
    android:id="@+id/btn_way_bill_click"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    app:font_button="consolas">
```

now i'm define some Button programical into project and i want to use `consolas` font defined into `font_button` by:

```
button.setTextAppearance(context, R.attr.font_button);
```

but i get error for this code and i can not resolve problem, i'm define custom class extends from Button like with this:

```
public class ButtonTextStyle extends Button {
    private Context mContext;
    public ButtonTextStyle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ButtonTextStyle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        init(attrs,-1);
    }

    public ButtonTextStyle(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        init(null,-1);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle) {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.ButtonTextStyle, defStyle, 0);
            String str = a.getString(R.styleable.ButtonTextStyle_font_button);
            switch (Integer.parseInt(str)) {
                case 0:
                    str = "fonts/consolas.ttf";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    str = "fonts/times.ttf";
                    break;
            }
            setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance(getContext()).loadFont(str));
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

```
Expected resource of type style
```

and i can not set for example enum to widgets like with set `times` font

**HOW to** set programical this custom class with attribute defined into `attr.xml`

**UPDATED:**
my class to add button is below method. i want to set font for it programically:

```
private void addButton(final CDialog owner, final Dialog dialog, final DialogButton dlgBtn) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tsw__layerButton);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 70);
    //layoutParams.setMargins(11, 0, 8, 0);

    Button button = new Button(context);
    if (buttonTheme != -1) {
        button.setBackgroundResource(buttonTheme);
    }
    button.setPadding(0,2,0,0);
    button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    button.setText(buttonMsg[dlgBtn.ordinal()]);
    button.setTextSize(14);
    button.setTextColor(G.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white_text));
    button.setWidth(dpToPx(buttonWidth));
    //button.setHeight(dpToPx(32));
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (dialogListener != null) {
                dialogListener.onCloseDialog(owner, dlgBtn);
            }
        }
    });
    linearLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Comment: but....what's the error?

Comment: @Leo topic updated sir

Comment: if you create your custom view by calling new ButtonTextStyle() so what xml file are you talking about?

Comment: why don't you use new ButtonTextStyle() ?

Comment: @pskink i can not use ButtonTextStyle inside programically to set font defined into attributes

Comment: so what is your custom class used for?

Comment: @pskink my custom class for create Button? i'm could not use defined font enum attributes in attr.xml for Button or other xml widgets.please read full my topic :)

Comment: so tell me why did you create a custom Button class which you don't use anywhere? what's the point of that?

Comment: @pskink yes sir `ButtonTextStyle` is my custom class extended from Button and i dont have problem to use it inside xml

Comment: so use it like this: new ButtonTextStyle() and add a setter to set the font, otherwise how can you get an instance of your custom class?

Comment: @pskink thanks can you complete your code

Comment: what code?  what do you mean?

Comment: @pskink `private void addButton` is my function to add button. please help me to set `ButtonTextStyle` declare-styleable to button

Comment: just follow @Leo answer, all he says is right

Comment: @Leo i'm Tired sir for testing and resolve problem. can you edit my `addButton` function ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this article will help you [Android: Set Custom Attributes Programmatically and Via XML](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com/2013/09/android-set-custom-attributes-via.html). Note, that there should be a style assigned to the `R.attr.font_button` attribute somewhere (for example in "AppTheme"). Because it's just an attribute, and it *holds a reference to a value*.

If you assigned a style in "AppTheme":

```
ButtonTextStyle button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_way_bill_click);
Resources.Theme themes = getTheme();
TypedValue storedValueInTheme = new TypedValue();
if (themes.resolveAttribute(R.attr.font_button, storedValueInTheme, true))
    button.setTextAppearance(storedValueInTheme.data);
```

Or if you declared your own theme. It can be declared as follows

```
<resources>
    <style name="ConsolasBtn" parent="@android:style/Widget">
        <item name="font_button">consolas</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then you need to apply this theme to your button. Try

```
ButtonTextStyle button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_way_bill_click);
button.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.ConsolasBtn);  // *this* refers to Context
```

Or try to pass `R.style.ConsolasBtn` to your constructor `ButtonTextStyle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)` as the `defStyle` argument.

See also [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), [Resources.Theme](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html), [TypedValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html), [attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504967/can-someone-explain-the-attr).

Comment: now how to set `consolas` attribute font via programical ?? `font_button` is enum and i can not choose `consolas` from it

Comment: @mahdipishguy I've updated my answer. But I can not guarantee that it works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the proper way to achieve what you are trying to do is by first declaring an enum attribute...

```
<declare-styleable name="ButtonTextStyle">
    <attr name="font_button" format="enum"> 
        <enum name="consolas"      value="0" />
        <enum name="times"    value="1" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Only change from your original code is the `format` attribute. Then you can declare those custom style attributes as below...

```
<com.sample.app.Widgets.ButtonTextStyle
    android:id="@+id/btn_way_bill_click"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    app:font_button="consolas">
```

but, don't forget to declare the namespace(s) your sub-widget belongs to in the parent layout, otherwise you won't be able to reference the `app` alias

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.sample.app.Widgets">
```

and finally, your `init` method would look something like this...

```
private void init(AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle) {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            int i = -1;
            TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.ButtonTextStyle, defStyle, 0);

            try{
                a.getInt(R.styleable.ButtonTextStyle_font_button, -1);
            }
            finally{
               a.recycle();
            }

            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    str = "fonts/consolas.ttf";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    str = "fonts/times.ttf";
                    break;
            }

            setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance(getContext()).loadFont(str));
        }
    }
```

### Setting the property programmatically

To set that property programmatically, you will need to expose a "setter" method that takes an integer value, then based on that value you can change the type face. To make things easier for consumers of your custom widget you can also define two constants in your class...

```
public static final int CONSOLAS = 0;
public static final int TIMES = 1;
```

then define the setter method...

```
  public void setFontButton(int fontButton) {
        if (fontButton != CONSOLAS && fontButton != TIMES) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "fontButton must be one of CONSOLAS or TIMES");
        }

        //load the font and set it here, the same way you did in "init"
    }
```

All you have to do is call that setter method and pass in one of the constants specified...

```
buttonTextStyle1.setFontButton(ButtonTextStyle.CONSOLAS);
```

### Yet ANOTHER Update

Instead of doing...

```
  Button button = new Button(context);
```

do...

```
 ButtonTextStyle button = new ButtonTextStyle(context);
```

and make sure you import the correct class so it can be used in code...

```
 import com.sample.app.Widgets.ButtonTextStyle;
```

Comment: i say i dont have any problem to set attribute via xml, my problem is set that programical

Comment: thanks sir. i want to set `app:font_button="consolas"` like with xml via programical :)

Comment: thanks sir, i can use this method. my widgets is Button and i'm define that by this way: `Button button = new Button(context);` and i dont know whats `buttonTextStyle1` and my app could not detect `ButtonTextStyle.CONSOLAS`

Comment: Your widget is `ButtonTextStyle`...unless I'm missing something. If you cast `button` to `ButtonTextStyle` you should have no problems...I'm pretty sure you know what I'm saying otherwise you wouldn't be able to write all that code in first place

Comment: hope this help, mate. If you happen to have more doubts. Please post a different question!!!!